# App Crashing with NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm pretty new to iOS, and I have no idea how to find a decent stacktrace like JAVA, so all I can find on why it's crashing is, "sigabrt".

I know it has something to do with this code I just added.

```
-(void) clearGame {
    for (CCSprite *sprite in placedSprites) {
        if(sprite == nil) continue;
        [self removeChild:sprite cleanup:NO];
        [placedSprites removeObject:sprite];
    }
    placedSprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1000];
}
```

Where the class I'm adding this to is a Layer in cocos2d. In it's init method, I have

```
placedSprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1000];
```

I don't know what could be wrong, so any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: When you see just "SIGABRT" and no stack trace nor the details of the exception, add an "Exception breakpoint" in XCode. Details at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot remove an object from a `NSMutableArray` while fast-enumerating (see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html)).

You could add the objects (which should be removed) to a separate `NSMutableArray` and remove the objects from this array from your 'main' array:

```
NSMutableArray *discardedItems = [NSMutableArray array];
SomeObjectClass *item;

for (item in originalArrayOfItems) {
    if ([item shouldBeDiscarded])
        [discardedItems addObject:item];
}

[originalArrayOfItems removeObjectsInArray:discardedItems];
```

Also see [Removing object from NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757046/removing-object-from-nsmutablearray) and [Best way to remove from NSMutableArray while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111866/best-way-to-remove-from-nsmutablearray-while-iterating).